# Where do stack pointer differences to stack base originate from on Linux?

Tags: linux, aslr, glibc

Let's assume we have this simple program:

```
void main() {
    int x;
    printf("%p", &x);
}
```

Assuming the stack is mapped something like this:

```
0x007ffffffdd000 0x007ffffffff000 0x00000000000000 rw- [stack]
```

I might get an output like this:

```
0x7fffffffd84c
```

If I calculate the difference to the base (`0x7fffffffd84c - 0x007ffffffdd000`) I get different values every time the program is executed.

At which point during process initialization is this difference introduced? Specifically I would also be interested in the code that does it (It is probably in the interpreter or in libc but I am not sure where to look)
Also what is the reasoning here, why is a random stack base not enough?

Comment: The stack is continuous, randomizing its top is also randomizing its bottom. See [this](https://0x434b.dev/an-introduction-to-address-space-layout-randomization-aslr-in-linux/).

Comment: Thanks for the resource, very good writeup. Pretty much exactly what I was looking for